# Local cartesian closedness in the category of compactly generated spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, ct.category-theory

According the [the nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compactly+generated+space#local_cartesian_closure_14), the category of compactly generated (CG) spaces is not locally cartesian closed.
So if $A$ is a CG space and $C$ a CG space above $A$, $C$ may not be exponentiable.

What if we require that $C$ is fibrant over $A$?
**If $C\to A$ is a (Serre) fibration, is $C$ exponentiable in the category of CG spaces above $A$?**

Comment: I doubt it.  (-: